# Is there something wrong with my code as logic in function works fine in js?

Tags: karate

```
* def a = ["a","b"]
* def b = ["1","2"]
* def fun =
"""
function(a,b){
var result={}
a.forEach(function(x,i){result[x]=b[i]});
return result;}
"""

* def final = fun(a,b)
* print final
```

Now what I am expecting is
{
"a":"1",
"b":"2"
}
but what I got is   {
"a":null,
"b":null
}?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are limitations to the JS blocks in Karate, that's how it is.

Do this instead:

```
karate.forEach(a, function(x,i){result[x]=b[i]});
```